# Interacting with html file from controller using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I am currently trying to create a controller to interact with an html file using Thymeleaf. After a while I noticed that perhaps my controller (more specifically the @PostMapping) isn't interacting with my html page at all. The reason I thought this is because no matter what input I placed as email/password (be it correct or incorrect) it would always link me to (/login?error). I tested out a simple conditional that would print "HERE" on the html page once the Post request is called to see if that was truly the case. The print never occurs. The point of this post is to understand why this simple post request is being ignored. Since I a making a simple Post request, I would assume that the "Here" would get printed no matter what.

My html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form th:action="@{/login}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
        
        <div th:if="${here}">
            <p>HERE</p>
        </div>
        
        <div>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{email}">
        </div>
    
        <div>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{password}" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My Controller class

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    
    UserRepository userRepo;
    UserService userService;
    
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "login";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String loginUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("here", true);

        return "login";
    }
}
```

My Spring Security Configurations

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    public WebSecurityConfig(UserService userService, BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .antMatchers("/registration/**", "/login")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();;
        
        return http.build();
    }

    
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAutenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        return provider;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wild guess, you are using Spring Boot with Spring Security without further configuration.

Comment: Nope, I configured it to permit access to "/login". I added my configurations to show them above.

Comment: The POST of `/login` is handled by Spring Security and **not** your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

come on, first you need a controller for your `home` page..

```
@RequestMapping("/home")
public String home() {
    return "home";
}
```

then need to configure the `security` to:

1 - consider `email` and `password` for authentication.

2 - configure the `home` page as the default login page.

3 - configure logout page, the spring default is `/login?logout`, but I'll show you a way to return a variable as a parameter.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .antMatchers("/registration/**", "/login")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .usernameParameter("email")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true)
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?unverified-email"); //unverified email variable.
    
    return http.build();
}
```

done that, your login should be successful and go to the home page.

to validate if the email has been verified, you must first have the login validated, so that the user is found correctly, and having the user validated, you can check if the email has been verified. The easiest way, is when you get redirected to `/home`, you can get the username and validate that the email is verified, if not, you redirect back to `/login?unverified-email`.

so then your controller would look something like this:

```
UserService userService;

@RequestMapping("/home")
public String home() {
User user = userService.getUser();
if(!user.verified)
    return "redirect:/login?unverified-email";

    return "home";
}
```

`UserService`

```
public User getUser() {
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    String user;
        
    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
        user = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();    
    } else {
    user = principal.toString();
    }
    return repository.findByEmail(user);
}
```

and on the login page, to show the unverified email message, you can add something like:

```
<div th:if="${param.unverified-email}">
    User not confirmed, please confirm your Email.
</div>
```

Of course, maybe it's not the best way to do it, but it worked for me.

Comment: I made the changes you mentioned, it seems to take into account correct inputs. But it gives me a "Whitelabel Error Page". I added ".defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true)" as you've done in your github but it still gives the error instead of displaying my home.html. When I place incorrect inputs it still redirects me to "/login?error", but I want my post request to return custom error messages (for example if user exists but hasn't confirmed his account print message "You haven't confirmed your account check your email.") It still seems as though my Post request in my controller is being ignored.

Comment: did you map something to '/home' in the controller? you need to have mapping to be able to be redirected '/home' to page home.html

Comment: @Ayoub Elmo, If you want to return a custom message for an incorrect login, you can do that by adding .failureUrl("/failedLogin") in your security configuration. Then write the endpoint for the /failedLogin url and add whatever message etc. Also, that Whitelabel Error Message means that you don't have an error.html in your project (Spring, by default, redirects to error.html whenever an error occurs but since you don't have it, you're faced with that Whilelabel error.

Comment: @Ayoub Elmo, I just changed my answer, I think now you can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

So, in order to handle incorrect logins, you have several options. To specify a different page (from the login page) that'll handle login errors, you can call failureUrl("/loginFailure") in Spring security.

But if you still want to use the same login page/request (e.g /login ) to handle the login errors, you can do that by providing an endpoint for GET /login (note that POST /login is handled by Spring security as someone mentioned in a comment) where you check if the url contains a parameter by the name of "error".

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public ModelAndView loginUser(ModelAndView mv, 
        HttpServletRequest request) {
 //for failed logins, the query string is equal to error
 String queryStr = request.getQueryString();
 if(queryStr != null && "error".equals(queryStr)){
    mv.addObject("errorMsg", "wrong credentials");
    mv.setViewName("errorPage");
 }else {
   //process other scenarios
 }


 return mv;
}
```

Now, in Thymeleaf you can simply check the value of errorMsg and display a appropriate message to the user.